# Azure Functions not displaying logs in Monitoring

Tags: python, logging, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I've created an Azure Function App with python and have published an app that runs every 5 minutes. I used to go to the **Function > Monitoring** to see the last 30 day runs. I've checked today and all logs have disappeared and the function does not display any runs in the Overview
[image]

The last time I checked before this happened, I had loads of logs in here but now I have none. I know the function is running because if I go to Application Insight into Live Monitoring I can see the traces and also can check that the results are being processed. I haven't changed anything to the script and not sure why this is happening. Has anyone experienced this and found a fix?

[image]

**EDIT**

I've recreated the Function App and noticed that it creates a **DefaultResourceGroup-XXX** resource group with a Default Workspace in it which I remember deleting it when I first created the Function App. I've left it on and now I see the logs in Monitoring but cannot see any connections to the Function App itself. Does anyone know how does this workspace relate to the logs and is there a way I can create a more user-friendly workspace name and link it to the App?

Comment: Go to the application insights of the Function App (if it is not configured - then create one), and try to see the exceptions table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [sheldonzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7252805/sheldonzy). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

On your function App go to monitor there if application insights is enabled you will see an option of **Run Query in Application Insights**

[image]

Open run query and check exception tables in application insights

[image]